# Cocoa swift - Slow loading data on tableview

Tags: swift, cocoa

I have a function that load songs information to the tableview. It very slow if I select a playlist that contain more than 20 songs.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    if tableColumn?.identifier == "TitleCol" {
        if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "TitleCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
            do{
                let library = try ITLibrary(apiVersion: "1.1")

                let thePlaylist = library.allPlaylists

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.textField?.stringValue = thePlaylist[self.playlist_index - 1].items[row].title
                }
                return cell
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    } else {
        if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "NumberCell", owner: self) as? NSTableCellView {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = String(row + 1)
            return cell
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

But the problem is that when I start scrolling, the tableView is very laggy.

Comment: Getting the (same) data source in each call of `viewForColumn:Row:` is **very** expensive. Move the lines `let library = try ITLibrary(apiVersion: "1.1")` and `let thePlaylist = library.allPlaylists` to a location where it's called only once. I recommend also to use Cocoa Bindings which makes the entire datasource method `viewForColumn:Row:` obsolete.

Comment: Wow, what a simple idea, thank mate. It worked